An 80s/90s TV series of a family that appear to be in another universe
I am trying to find the title of a TV show I remember watching (possibly in the late 80s/early 90s.
It isn't "Otherworld".
It featured a family of 4.  They were on the run from someone and seemed to be on different planets in different episodes. The youngest son was blond.
Things I remember: on one planet they discovered that the ruling people were able to extract people's youth by kissing them.
On another planet one of the sons was running away from someone and ended up covering his trainers in mud before getting on a yellow school bus.  A girl asked why he was muddying his trainers and he said it was to keep his feet cool...
I can see the boy but cannot describe him.
I remember very weird specific details like that but cannot for the life of me remember the title!

American accents by chance? At least it would eliminate all the 1970s BBC weirdness.

@Vicpylon If the word "trainers" was used in the show to mean "sneakers", then it wasn't an American production. :-)

I caught that but that may be a function of writer's unconscious writing habits.  Hence my clarification question.
